# What determines the gain from the Honor policy and Aztec unique ability? 

Tags: civilization-5

[Honor](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=427485) now grants culture when barbarians are killed and grants gold per unit killed later on. The Aztec (BLAST YOU AND YOUR SHINY GODS...ahem...) unique ability grants culture when a unit is killed. What determines the amount of culture/gold gained after each kill?

Just from playing I seem to earn more from the more advanced units but I was hoping for a formula.

Comment: I know that honor grants the exact same amount that the Aztec get... but I don't remember how much they get :( I'm pretty sure it depended on the killed unit strength / cost / era.

Comment: @Oak I've been reading civfanatics looking for a formula but no luck yet. The closest I've gotten is the unit strength / turn are involved, but wasn't any sort of confirmation beyond that.

Comment: @Oak and Honor + Aztec = doubled bonus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to my testing:

> Aztec culture from kills =
>   Honor culture from barbarians =
>   Honor finisher gold from kills =
>   **COMBAT STRENGTH OF KILLED UNIT**

So killing a Pikeman (strength 10) as Aztec with full honor tree gives 10 culture and 10 gold.

Notes:

- Ranged units provide culture/gold according to their regular strength, not ranged strength.
- Only the base strength is considered, bonuses (terrain / great general / promotions etc.) do not matter.
- Killing a unit with a city does not generate culture or gold (or xp).
- If you're supposed to get both culture and gold from a kill, only one of the floating numbers will appear, either purple or yellow; but both values are correctly awarded.
- Culture awards from Aztec UA and from the Honor opener stack, so barbarian units provide `2 x strength` culture per kill in that case.
- The culture is only credited to your civ total.  It does not get credited to any city and therefore does not help increase your borders.