# Pink number when clearing barbarian encampments?

Tags: civilization-5

After clearing a barbarian encampment, a pink number appears above the tile where the encampment was. What does this number mean?

Example:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Psst! The bigger picture is better, but you're still missing freehand circles!

Comment: @RavenDreamer How's that?

Comment: You tell me, once your OMG-freehand-circle upvotes start accruing!

Comment: While I did find this question interesting, I didn't upvote it at first. Your last edit however... I don't know why, but I feel I didn't give this question a chance the first time I saw it, which I have since remedied.

Comment: Such power, who knew that the freehand-circle was the key all this time.

Comment: @MrSmooth - Yeah, there's just something compelling about it... I feel like I should upvote!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whenever small pink numbers show up like that, it refers to bonus culture, contributing towards your next social policy unlock.

I'm not sure the exact specifics in your case, since there's a couple of different ways to get culture from winning combat.

Comment: The specifics are that he's likely playing Aztec, [Aztec get a culture bonus from killing stuff](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/25453/27134), and it's likely that the barbarians he killed had a combat strength of 4.

Comment: @pixel I was playing as the Greeks at the time, so it must be something else.

Comment: Strange, I can't see any obvious culture bonuses from kills as Greece, how far through the game are you/what social policies do you have/what message was shown when you captured the encampment?

Comment: I'm going to take a second guess at you having the opening policy from the 'honor' tree - *Adopting Honor gives a +25% combat bonus VS Barbarians, and notifications will be provided when new Barbarian Encampments spawn in revealed territory. **Gain Culture for the empire from each barbarian killed.***

Comment: @pixel That's correct, mystery solved :-)