# What does it mean when the borderlands symbol flashes on my screen?

Tags: borderlands-2

Occasionally when playing, I see the symbol below appear. It usually flashes for a moment and then disappears.

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: Ah yes, the freehand circle - [faithful friend](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80864/pink-number-when-clearing-barbarian-encampments) of the Arqade user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the autosave icon; it indicates your game has been saved. There's a screen that explains that either when the game starts up or as one of the Loading Screen tips.

Comment: It's a requirement for console certification, and although it's not a requirement on PC it's easier for Gearbox to leave it in rather than remove it.

Comment: Figures. I kept searching around when I saw it, thinking it meant there was a vault symbol nearby or something :P

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Borderlands 2 in specific as I don't have it, but in a great many other games that indicates an autosave going on in the background.

Normally you're given a warning when you start the game saying "don't turn off when this happens, it's bad".